# Не получается создать проект C++ в Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Когда я пытаюсь создать/открыть проект Visual C++, я получаю такое сообщение:
[image: Сообщение,появляющееся при запуске]

Была ли у кого-нибудь такая же проблема?

Comment: какой релиз стоит, старый превью? у них таких багов , проявляющихся после обновлений, до фига и больше.Единственный ответ от Микрософт - переустанавливайте, беря новый релиз.

Comment: У меня на 2017 Enterprise все хорошо, странно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено с помощью простого обновления пакетов в Visual Studio 2017 Community. Спасибо всем :)